# mongodb difference between find and equal operator

Tags: mongodb

What is the difference between

```
db.MarketDataReference.find({ "CutVersion" : { "$eq" : 8649781 } })
```

**and**

```
db.MarketDataReference.find({ "CutVersion" : 8649781 })
```

Second statement gives me results while first one doesn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no [*difference*](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/eq/#equals-a-specified-value) those two query are the same.

**Demo**

```js
> db.bar.insert({ 'a': 4 })
> db.bar.find({ 'a': 4 })
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5524ef4f374c8649d5cfb3b5"), "a" : 4 }
> db.bar.find({'a': { "$eq": 4 }})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5524ef4f374c8649d5cfb3b5"), "a" : 4 }
```